# Perl Net::FTP download to a specific directory

Tags: perl, ftp

I'm able to download files from an ftp-server (with subdirectories) locally on my PC.

```
    $f->get($file2);
```

The files are downloaded to the working directory C:/wd where I started the perl-script. I would like to download the files in another directory, for example, C:/wd/sub or C:/another. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the [Net::FTP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aFTP) documentation page, you'll see that get() accepts a second argument that determines the location that the file will be saved.

So, you'd just do `$f->get($file2,'C:/another/filename');`

Comment: Thank for help. Sincerly, I read the doc but I thought it ask for a filename if the name should be change of the file ("LOCAL_FILE may be a filename or a filehandle."). I didn't thought so far to add also the path.

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly state, files are downloaded to your current working directory, so just chdir() before you get(). I mean locally, and nothing to do with Net::FTP. E.g.

```
chdir "/tmp";
$f->get(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Net::FTP get accepts filehandle as LOCAL_FILE.

```
use Path::Tiny;   #for path
my $local_file = path($out_dir, $file);
open my $local_fh, ">", $local_file or die "Can't write to $local_file:$!";
$ftp->get($file, $local_fh);
```